# Trying to implement Bootstrap 4 in Django Project.Getting issue in Navbar Dropdown when adding link to custom css

Tags: html, css, django

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ml/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}"/>
<script src="{% static 'ml/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{% static 'ml/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

When I removed main.css link in my code dropdown is shown but including main.css in my code, dropdown is not displayed.I want to customize bootstrap code by adding custom style file for it but getting issue.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand"  href="#">Yartsa</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
</li>


  <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="Arquivos">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"  data-target="#Arquivos" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Projects
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" id="MyArqs">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logistic Regression</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Misspellings</a>

    </div>
     <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

main.css

```
.bg-dark {
background-color:rgb(52, 115, 231)!important;
 }
.navbar-brand {
font-size: 2.00rem;
}
```

Comment: You make your css property `!important` see how to make important property in css

Comment: I able to change the color of my navbar from my main.css file. My main issue is dropdown menu is not displayed when I include my main.css otherwise it is being displayed.

Comment: Can you add main.css after `bootstrap.min.js` try this

Comment: Which version of bootstrap you use?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.4.1

Comment: you add main.css after all link or script tag try this and let me know ! i copy your code and run, dropdown work fine,you try link main.css after all script link

Comment: Previously it was not working, now it is working fine with the same code. Thank you

Comment: can you make help full flag on my comment